# Build a disconnected graph with an interesting constraint (Mathematical Proof.)

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

You are given an integer $n.$ Determine if there is an unconnected graph with  vertices that contains at least two connected components and contains the number of edges that is equal to the number of vertices. Each vertex must follow one of these conditions:

1 .  Its degree is less than or equal to $1.$

2 .  It's a $\text{cut-vertex}$.

Note: The graph must be simple. Loops and multiple edges are not allowed.

I solved the above question by hit and trial method, and the answer comes out to be $12.$

We need at-least $12$ or more vertex for all the above conditions to be satisfied.

But, I am unable to come up with a Mathematical proof.

Comment: I presume you made a component with 6 vertices and 6 edges, and then decided that you need two of them giving you n=12 vertices/edges. You can also make a component with 8 vertices and 9 edges, and together with one loose vertex you can get n=9.